# What is rotational diffusion and lateral diffusion in plasma membrane?

Tags: plasma-membrane

There are no good reads on internet. The idea that I have formed so far of these topics, is that lateral diffusion is translational movement of protein in a leaflet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this paper](http://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/14/11/21561/htm), rotational diffusion describes the movement of a membrane lipid around its axis that is perpendicular to the plane of the bilayer, analogous to a person spinning around while standing up.

Lateral diffusion describes the movement of membrane lipids exchanging places with each other across a face of the bilayer, rather like two dancers spinning about their mutual center of gravity.

[image: Different types of diffusion of membrane phospholipids]